# Can a aspnetcore api controller "lose" tasks run without await?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm getting a little lost between processes, threads etc.

Essentially, I'm just trying to find a standard way of doing something on an incoming request, that might take 5-300 seconds without the client having to wait that long for a response.

Given the code below, can any of the numbered ways of calling the long running method be swallowed?
As in, can this ever happen?

1. Enter endpoint (second 0)
2. Start long running task
3. Return response (second 2)
4. At second 2? 5? 30? this... instance/thread/call/execution environment just shuts down because its "done". I'm "done" because my response is sent.

OR is the long running task itself keeping the... instance/thread/call alive? Or is an api just always alive?

```
    public async Task<ActionResult<int>> Get()
    {
        // second 0
        //... 
        var threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

        DoSomething60sAsync(); // #1 Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.
        _ = DoSomething60sAsync(); // #2 No Warning

        Task.Run(DoSomething60sAsync); // #3 Same Warning as #1
        _ = Task.Run(DoSomething60sAsync); // # 4 No Warning

        return Ok(threadId); // second 2
    }

    private async Task DoSomething60sAsync()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
        {
            var threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

            Console.WriteLine(threadId + ": Second " + i);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I tried to look at the threads. I noticed they're ALL background threads. I also noticed that the threadId seems completely random. It even changes within that for loop.
I read that aspnetcore threading is complicated.

Given that they're all background threads anyway, using `Task.Run` in #3/#4 seems pointless.

Another way of solving this problem I read about is implementing a `IHostedService` and some kind of TaskRunner-BackgroundQueue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Also there is Hangfire.

I tried all of these and they all **seem to** work. So I would like to use the simplest solution, but I'm worried that just "calling tasks without await" will be lost somehow. Is this a valid concern? Can this ever happen?

Answer (score 0):

> Essentially, I'm just trying to find a standard way of doing something on an incoming request, that might take 5-300 seconds without the client having to wait that long for a response.

There are a few names for this. I've called it "basic distributed architecture", but "asynchronous messaging" is also common. The [core idea](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html) is that you need two things:

1. A durable queue.
2. A backend process.

> At second 2? 5? 30? this... instance/thread/call/execution environment just shuts down because its "done". I'm "done" because my response is sent.
> OR is the long running task itself keeping the... instance/thread/call alive? Or is an api just always alive?

Loss of work is certainly possible. [Shutdowns are normal](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-2-durable-queues.html#:%7E:text=when%20it%E2%80%99s%20not.-,Shutdowns%20Are%20Normal), and when the hosting process is shut down, work *can* be lost.

> Given that they're all background threads anyway, using Task.Run in #3/#4 seems pointless.

On ASP.NET Core, yes, that is true. Also, the discard (`_ =` ) is literally just telling the compiler "I know what I'm doing; don't give me a warning", so you're not getting a warning on those lines because the warning is silenced - the code is still just as dangerous (i.e., you'll still lose work).

> Another way of solving this problem I read about is implementing a IHostedService and some kind of TaskRunner-BackgroundQueue.

To prevent loss of work, your queue has to be durable (saved on disk).

> Also there is Hangfire.

Hangfire (or an `IHostedService` connected to a durable queue) is one way to implement asynchronous messaging. I [tend to prefer background services in separate processes for reasons described on my blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-3-backend-processor.html), but a background service inside the ASP.NET Core process would also work.